# Zoom high quality of the image to full detail without loading a large image on iPhone

Tags: iphone, image

I need to develop a feature into an iPhone app which will allow the user to zoom in very much on an image and display high-quality details of the image without loading the large and loading it online. I've found a example here: developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/ but it dont seems to zoom at full details,
And the images are store locally.

I have seem apple developer example like PhotoScroller, scrollviewsuite.
but feels they work differently just cutting the image in tiles.

Is it Possible To access asynchronously chunk of data and render it to view at same time in didReceivedData function delegate.

Please provide some tutorial or example.
Thanks
Avinash

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you have said, PhotoScroller is really what you are describing. It is the only example that I know that can handle HUGE images and only display what is needed. I have used it for 100 megapixel images and it works great.

Comment: Well what is the error? You will have to give us a little bit more to go on than that if you want any kind of help with it.

Comment: PhotoScrollerNetwork sample code i have got have some issue while retriving online image the decodeImageURL function seems to not working and crashes

Comment: Was able to run the code PhotoscrollerNetwork,but it also first download the image data chunks and write to file and then draws at end.

Comment: Here is what you want, its called 'PhotoScroller'not 'PhotoScrollerNetwork' https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080